# Angular Partial Submit/Process

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am not familiar with angular or jquery etc. I was playing with `JSF` for longer. Is there way `partial submit/process` and easy to write? I would like to know `partial page processing`.

Example - *Is there some feature in `angularjs`?*

```
<div id="div1">
    here some input

    <button type="button" ng-update="div1" id ="btn1"/>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    here some input

    <button type="button" ng-update="div2"  id ="btn2"/>
</div>

<button type="button" ng-update="div1 div2"  id ="btn3"/>
```

My expectation is

```
Click `bnt1` -> only `div1` will be process.
Click `bnt2` -> only `div2` will be process.
Click `bnt3` -> Both of `div1` and `div2` will be process.
```

Answer (score 3):

No this is not needed in Angular, it's always refreshing the whole page.  If you want some values in div 1 to change, just update the variables in your controller and the screen reflects the changes automatically.

Comment: Up vote :)  I will go and test it first. I will come back here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular was built to solve exactly this problem. If you need to control only part of the page, consider building a directive. That will come later. For now, check out this article that introduces angular:

http://tinyurl.com/m4mvf6z

Good luck!